# reading a dataset features of X values into their own array column and y (target) into its array but WITHIN main array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to read my csv file to give me this array of arrays as follows:

```
[[[1.1, 1.2],[+1.0]],
 [[2.3, 1.0],[+1.0]],
 [[2.9, 2.8],[-1.0]],
 [[5.2, 1.2],[+1.0]],
 [[5.4, 4.1],[+1.0]]
]
```

In the main array, the first array part [1.1, 1.2] represents X columns (x1, x2) and the second part [+1.0] is the target column (y values). How can this be achieved in python? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found a solution that seems to work:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=r',', fieldnames=(0,1, 'y')) #0 is column x1, 1 is column x2, and 'y' is the target column (y values)
    headers = next(f) #to remove the first header row names
z = [[[float(row[0]), float(row[1])], [float(row['y'])]] for row in reader] #create the array of arrays
z #display the array of arrays as needed.
```

output

```
[[[1.1, 1.2],[+1.0]],
 [[2.3, 1.0],[+1.0]],
 [[2.9, 2.8],[-1.0]],
 [[5.2, 1.2],[+1.0]],
 [[5.4, 4.1],[+1.0]]
]
```